# React useEffect hook, is there a point of having dependencies when a dependency is a deeply nested object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using a useEffect hook and I have a deeply nested object as one of the dependencies. I use a usePrevious hook and lodash _.IsEqual to check for changes in the object and then I only execute the code in the useEffect if there is a change.

Given that there is the deeply nested object, doesn't it cause the useEffect hook to be executed on every render, doesn't that make the dependency array redundant?

Are these not same:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(!_.isEqual(data, prevData)) {
    // do something with data and otherDependency
  }
},[data, prevData, otherDependency])

useEffect(() => {
  if(!_.isEqual(data, prevData)) {
    // do something with data and otherDependency
  }
})
```